# SQL recursive query (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I don't know how to do an SQL recursive query.
The database structure is like this:

```
Name               Id  Id Parent
Food                0   -1 
Pizza               1    0 
Pasta               2    0 
Pasta with Tomato   3    2
```

Every Row has a name, an ID (which is the primary key in the table) and a parent id, that is recursive as you can see. If a row doesn't have a parent, then the id is set to -1. In the case of pasta with tomato, I need to take the parent name and, if the parent has a parent itself, I need to take also that name and so on until I reach the root. What is the right recursive query to apply?
Thanks to those that will help me!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL v8 has recursive CTE.

Comment: http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html

Comment: I'm using MySQL, and unfortunately I don't have either MySQL v8 or the possibility to update it

Comment: Follow the above link, and you can perhaps get some useful tips.

Comment: That would be perfect if I had PHP 8.. :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually had to do LEFT JOINs to expand the table to the desired layout:

```
select a.*, b.name as parent_name, b.ID as parent_id, c.ID_Parent as parent_ID2, 
       d.name as parent_name2
from [sample_tbl] a
left join [sample_tbl] b
on a.ID_parent = b.ID
left join [sample_tbl] c
on b.ID = c.ID
left join [sample_tbl] d
on c.ID_Parent = d.ID
;
```

Output:

| Name | ID | ID_Parent | parent_name | parent_id | parent_ID2 | parent_name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 0 | -1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Pizza | 1 | 0 | Food | 0 | -1 | NULL |
| Pasta | 2 | 0 | Food | 0 | -1 | NULL |
| Pasta with Tomato | 3 | 2 | Pasta | 2 | 0 | Food |

Comment: Are you sure this works properly? What if the tree of parents and children nests over even more levels? And how does this stuff with the brackets work in MySQL?